# How do I change where Steam installs to?

Tags: steam

I had a problem with Steam a while ago and had to re-install it. When I re-installed I somehow set it to install on my desktop and it cluttered my desktop with all of the files. I moved all of files into one folder and started up Steam, and on starting up it created all of the files again on my desktop after I had just moved them into one folder. I know the default install is C:\Program Files\Steam but mine is set to my desktop, so is there anyway that I can change it back to there without having to re-install?

Comment: Steam installs the games on your Desktop? You're absolutely certain those are not just shortcuts? Weird...

Comment: Don't you get an option to choose the installation location at install time?

Comment: @Studoku I don't recall having any problems when I installed Steam on my F drive, but it has been a couple of years...

Answer (score 2):

When you install a game from your steam library the following will appear:

[image: steam install screen]

Select the drop down box titled: *Choose location for install:* and you can select from steam locations, or create one on drives without one already.

You can alternatively manage your Steam library Folders from the steam settings, under *downloads*:

[image: steam settings > downloads]

Click the first button that says *STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS* under the heading: *Content Libraries* and from here you can set up the locations you want to install to.